# Let $a,b \in \mathbb R$ and $f(x)=a\cos x+b\cos3x$. Prove that $|b|\le 1$.

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

Let $a,b \in \mathbb R$ and $f(x)=a\cos x+b\cos3x$. It is known that $f(x)>1$ has no real solutions. Prove that $|b|\le 1$. We can write the given equality as 
\begin{align}
&f(x)=(a-3b)\cos x+4b\cos^3x\\[2ex]
\Rightarrow\quad&f'(x)=(3b-a)\sin x-12b\cos^2x\sin x=0\\[1ex]
\Rightarrow\quad&\sin x=0,\quad \cos^2x=\frac {3b-a}{12b}
\end{align}
Therefore $f(x)$ has minima or maxima when $\sin x=0$, so $\cos x=\pm 1$ or when $\cos x=\pm\sqrt{\frac {3b-a}{12b}}$. Hence $f(x)=\pm(a+b)$ or $\pm\frac 23(3b-a)$.

Now what should I do?

Comment: The assumption is that there is no $x$ such that $f(x)>1$?

Comment: I fixed $\cos3x$ in the text, because it reflects what follows

Comment: @Ian..it is not an assumption, it is given in the question..

Answer (score 5):

By plugging in for $x$, we obtain:
$$f(0)=b+a,\qquad f\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)=b-\frac{a}{2}$$
Since $f$ is continuous, it takes all values between $b+a$ and $b-a/2$ (regardless of which is larger/smaller). In particular, it takes on the value $b$. Since $f(x+\pi)=-f(x)$, it follows that $f$ also takes on the value $-b$. Since $f(x)>1$ has no real solutions, it follows that neither $b$ nor $-b$ exceed 1, i.e. $|b|\leq 1$.

Comment: why the result is independent of  $a$?

Comment: Because regardless of the value of $a$, the interval $[b-a/2,b+a]$ contains the value $b$. Note that if $a<0$, we should write $[b+a,b-a/2]$ instead.

Answer (score 0):

Setting $x=0, \pi$ and then $\pi/3, 2\pi/3$ we get
$$\pm(a+b)\le 1\\
\pm(a/2-b)\le 1$$
From the pictures of the solution sets of $|a+b|\le 1$ and $|a/2-b|\le 1$ we can conclude that $|b|\le 1$, as both contain the the vertical segment from $(0,-1)$ to $(0,1)$, but one goes up, the other goes down.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Setting $a=1,b=1.01,c=1.01$, we obtain one real solution, $\cos x=0.885831$ or $x=0.482515$, from equation (1):

$$f(x)=c>1\tag{1}$$

where
$$f(x):=(a-3b)\cos x+4b\cos^3x\tag{2}$$

Thus it seems to me that the condition $f(x)>1$ has no real solution is not enough to deduce that $|b|<1$.

Comment: why the donwn vote? Is my numerical calculation not correct?

Comment: @mike...could you explain how you arrived at the conclusion? P.S-i am not the one who downvoted you..

Comment: @mike, I didn't downvote either but it looks like you have misunderstood the problem. The condition is that $f(x)>1$ has no solution for any $x$. When you set $a=1,b=1.01$ as you have done, there is a trivial solution when $x=0$, for $f(0)=1+1.01>1$.